# Spring security - automatic logout after stopping the appliation.java is not working

Tags: spring, security

I'm using Spring Security tool in my project. When the project is started and localhost:8080 is accessed, login is mandatory. I read somewhere that once the application is stopped, the page shall logout automatically.

However, once the application is stopped and started again, on reloading the page localhost:8080, it remains logged in.

I was expecting that once the application is stopped and started again, upon attempting to access localhost:8080, login page should be displayed.

I tried using on incognito mode also expecting it might be due to cache however, it didn't logout.

Further, it asks to login the first time it is accessed on a new window and even parallel sessions are allowed.
It remains logged in unless /logout is used or, the browser window is closed.

I would appreciate if someone could also help in finding how to end the particular event or, track the event that is accessing the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to debug, without the actual code, but one of the reasons it could be happening due to usage of a library like `spring-devtools`, which sets persistent sessions from its default of `false` to `true`.

Please set the property `server.servlet.session.persistent=false` in application properties.